# How one can deduce that $tx≡2t[mod(z)]$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $x,y,z,t$ four positive integers.
If $$x≡2[mod(y)]$$ and
$$z=ty$$
Then how one can deduce that 
$$tx≡2t[mod(z)]$$

Comment: Your tags are quite wrong, this has nothing to do with either real analysis or real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x \equiv 2 [mod(y)]$ is equivalent to say that there exists an integer $n$ such that $x = 2 + ny$. Multiplying this last equation by $t$, you get $tx = 2t + n(ty) = 2t + nz$ or, equivalently, $tx \equiv 2t[mod(z)]$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
x=2 (\mod y)
$$
means that there exists a $k\in \mathbb Z$ such that $x=2+k*y$.

That means we can write $tx$ as $2t+k*t*y$, and then it should be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

$$\eqalign{
  x\equiv2\pmod y
  &\Rightarrow x-2=ky\quad\hbox{for some $k\in\Bbb Z$}\cr
  &\Rightarrow tx-2t=kty\quad\hbox{for some $k\in\Bbb Z$}\cr
  &\Rightarrow tx-2t=kz\quad\hbox{for some $k\in\Bbb Z$}\cr
  &\Rightarrow tx\equiv 2t\pmod z\ .\cr}$$